# Store type from external package in Hive database (no TypeAdapter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I try to store a type defined in an external package.
There is something I don't undertand:
How can I autogenerate the TypeAdapter if the class of this type is defined in an external package ?

Should I fork the package only to declare the `@HiveType` and `@HiveField`, to generate TypeAdapater ?

Or am I doomed to writing the TypeAdapter by hand ?

It's seems to be a common use case but I don't find any clear answer, every exemples use custom local class, not from external package.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without generating an adapter. You need to make a workaround, maybe an extension method or a utility function.
check these:

- https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/526#issuecomment-751380194
- https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/681#issue-904818485